# How does Linux buddy allocator determine which size order list to insert into when freeing block?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

The Binary Buddy Allocator used in Linux uses bitmaps where each bit corresponds to a state of a pair of buddy-blocks (taken from [this article](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html)). And the `void free_page(void *addr)` call doesn't take a size of the allocated block that is to be freed.

I don't understand how this algorithm does determine into which order list to insert a block being freed without knowing its size. Let's imagine we allocated all available memory, so all the bitmaps are zeroed. Now we call `free_page()` with some address, and it's not clear into which list should the block be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course `free_page(void *addr)` or the equivalent `__free_page(struct page *page)` do not need a second argument: their purpose is to free *one* page only, and the size of a single page is known. The `order` is always `0` in this case.

Freeing a block of pages is done through `__free_pages(struct page *page, unsigned int order)`, which does indeed take `order` as second argument.